# Will creating serializer.Serializer fields saves to the database?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

When we're not creating models and directly creating the fields inn serializers using serializer.Serializer , will the fields save to database? because we havent migrated to the database? also if i have created one existing database, i'm creating some additional fields in serializers? will that also saves to database?  can anyone lighten me up? Im new to django api.
here i provide some example.

let my **Model.Py** be like,

```
 class Detail(models.Model):
    fname = models.Charfield(maxlength=20)
    lname = models.Charfield(maxlength=20)
    mobile = models.IntergerField(maxlength=20)
    email = models.EmailField(maxlength=20)
```

let my **Serializer.Py** be like,

```
 class DetailSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
      created_at = serializer.Charfield
      is_active  = serializer.Booleanfield
```

Will this serializer save in database that i created manually in serializer?
another question is if i create serializers without a model, will that save to database?
if that saves in database how's it possible without migrating?

Comment: It won't happen automatically when you use serializer.Serializer,  it happen when you use model serializer and specify which the model to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

DRF won't create a field in your model table if you declare a field that doesn't exists in your model.

Actually, when using `ModelSerializer` and declare a field that does not exists in your model, you will get an error like `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name created_at is not valid for model Detail`. So you won't be able to use your serializer at all.

And when you are using `Serializer`, you don't have `create` method so you won't be able to save data on db at all.